# How to set the image and text of the check box margin or padding right

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Check box` as the below code:

```
DelayedAnimation(
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    title: const Text('Check privacy & policy'),
                    value: timeDilation != 1.0,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {
                        timeDilation = value ? 5.0 : 1.0;
                      });
                    },
                    secondary: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/policy_ic.png',
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  delay: delayedAmount + 4500,
                ),
```

and it's look like the below image:

[image: cb1]

Now I need to set padding or margin right for the `text` and image to be like the below image:

[image: cb2]

I hope some one could help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is simply wrap the *CheckboxListTile* in a *Padding* widget and only set the *horizontal* property.

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0), // Set it to your liking
                child: CheckboxListTile(
                      title: const Text('Check privacy & policy'),
                      value: timeDilation != 1.0,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                         setState(() {
                           timeDilation = value ? 5.0 : 1.0;
                         });
                      },
                      secondary: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/policy_ic.png',
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a row instead of the CheckboxListTile:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset(
        'assets/images/policy_ic.png',
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          'Check privacy & policy',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
        ),
      ),
      Checkbox(
          value: timeDilation != 1.0,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              timeDilation = value ? 5.0 : 1.0;
            });
          }),
    ],
  )
```

Edit:
Create a custom widget like this:

```
class CustomTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomTileState createState() => _CustomTileState();
}

class _CustomTileState extends State<CustomTile> {
  bool value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          value = !value;
        });
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.extension),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text(
              'Check privacy & policy',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
            ),
          ),
          Checkbox(
            value: value,
            onChanged: (bool value) {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but the problem now, the check box is the only part was clickable... I need all are clickable.. I meant that when click the icon or the text or the check box will be just one item :D

Comment: In this example code, _CustomTileState holds if the checkbox is checked or not. The checkbox itself just represents the status.